# Custom Odata formatter returning full database instead of resource

Tags: entity-framework, odata, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using a custom formatter to embed my result directly into a `<script>` tag. The formatter just adds a variable and serialize the entity. Here is an simplified implementation of my custom formatter:

```
        public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, System.Net.TransportContext transportContext)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
                {
                    var jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                    });

                    sw.Write("var values=" + jsonOutput + ";");
                }

            });
        }
```

This works fine if I request a resource with a `$filter`, `$select` or a `$expand`, but not if I just query a resource itself (e.g. `http://localhost:53662/Categories?$format=jsone`). Then however, the formatter serialize the **whole database**.

Here is the wrong result for `http://localhost:53662/Categories?$format=jsone` (as you can see, it also returns Products and Tags, which are not include in the Odata request):

[image: Wrong result with full db]

Here is an correct example, if I add a Odata query (here `http://localhost:53662/Categories?$format=jsone&$select=Name`):

[image: Good result with select query]

Here is the correct result without the custom formatter (`http://localhost:53662/Categories`):

[image: Normal request also works]

The Web API Controller are pretty simple:

```
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<Categories> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Categories> qOptions)
        {
            IQueryable<Categories> result = db.Categories;
            return result;
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public SingleResult<Categories> Get([FromODataUri] int key, ODataQueryOptions<Categories> qOptions)
        {
            IQueryable<Categories> result = db.Categories.Where(x => x.Id == key);
            return SingleResult.Create(result);
        }
```

Why does the custom formatter return the full database instead of just the requested resource?

Comment: Are you using lazy loading or ProxyClasses in entity framework? If yes try to disable the proxy creating DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; or use db.Categories.AsNoTracking() may help you

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm using Web API with ASP.MVC 4. You're using Web API 2, but it's kind of the same problem

In case you don't need that reference depth at all:
add to your reference list, contained in codefirst model, new attribute `[JsonIgnore]`

Example:

```
public class Subgroup
{
    public int SubgroupId { get; set; }
    public string SubgroupName { get; set; }
    //relations
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    //relations
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<Subgroup> Subgroups { get; set; } 
}
```

or you can just make it private (non-virtual).

In case you want to set up return result, try to work with [DataContract](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_media_type_formatter) attribute.

But we want to have a choice. Make it configurable (with own formatters).
And documentation doesn't give proper answer.
`JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.MaxDepth` and `JsonFormatter.MaxDepth` do nothing. But no harm in trying:

```
var jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
   ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
   MaxDepth = 1
});
```

What else can I suggest: you can write your own formatter using JavaScriptSerializer